# XNA 2D camera with horizontal scrolling boxes and collisions

Tags: xna, camera, scroll, 2d, collision-detection

I've got and XNA 2D game which I've been making, but I'm having problems with it.

I've got boxes scrolling across the screen which my sprite is jumping over. The sprite is being followed by a 2D camera, and I fear that the camera is causing issues, as it's causing the scrolling boxes to stop half way across the screen instead of continuing, and also the number of lives are decreasing rapidly rather than one life when one collision occurs.

This is the code in which my sprite collides with the moving boxes

```
    Rectangle fairyRectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);

        hit = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < GameConstants.TotalBoxes; i++)
        {
            if (scrollingBlocks.boxArray[i].alive)
            {
                Rectangle blockRectangle = new Rectangle((int)scrollingBlocks.boxArray[i].position.X, (int)scrollingBlocks.boxArray[i].position.Y, scrollingBlocks.boxArray[i].texture.Width, scrollingBlocks.boxArray[i].texture.Height);

                if (IntersectPixels(fairyRectangle, fairyTextureData, blockRectangle, blockTextureData))
                {
                    scrollingBlocks.boxArray[i].alive = false;



                    hit = true;
                    lives--;

                    scrollingBlocks.boxArray[i].alive = true;

                    scrollingBlocks.boxArray[i].position.X = random.Next(GameConstants.ScreenWidth);
                    scrollingBlocks.boxArray[i].position.Y = 570;
                }
            }

        }
```

And this is the update function in the scrolling boxes
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

```
        for (int i = 0; i < GameConstants.TotalBoxes; i++)
        {
            boxArray[i].position.X = boxArray[i].position.X - 5;
            boxArray[i].position.Y = boxArray[i].position.Y;

            if (boxArray[i].position.X < 0)
            {
                boxArray[i].position.X = randomno.Next(GameConstants.ScreenWidth) + 700;
                boxArray[i].position.Y = 570;
            }

            Helper.WrapScreenPosition(ref boxArray[i].position);
        }



    }
```

I want them to start at the right hand screen and move all the way across to x = 0, but they're currently stopping around halfway at x = 400.

And finally this is where I'm drawing it all, with the sprite and the block

```
    if (gameState == GameState.PLAYINGLEVEL3)
        {
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Aquamarine);
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend);
            backgroundManager.Draw(spriteBatch);
            //scrollingBlocks.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(lucidaConsole, "Score: " + score + " Level: " + level + " Time Remaining: " + ((int)timer / 1000).ToString() + " Lives Remaining: " + lives, scorePosition, Color.DarkOrchid);
            spriteBatch.End();


            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend, SpriteSortMode.Deferred, SaveStateMode.None, camera.transform);
            scrollingBlocks.Draw(spriteBatch);
            fairyL3.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided I can't tell much about how your camera works but my guess is that when you start the level your camera picks a new center point(rather than the original xna screen location)

In other words, the center of the camera may have pushed it back a bit, so what you think is position 0 of the screen may have been pushed forward to the middle of the screen making the boxes stop. I'd suggest looking at these camera tutorials http://www.david-amador.com/2009/10/xna-camera-2d-with-zoom-and-rotation/ or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pin8_ZfBgq0

Cameras can be tricky so I'd suggest looking at a few tutorials to get the hang out matrices and view ports.

As for the lives taking away more than one, It's because your saying "If this box is colliding with my player, take away lives." the computer doesn't know that you only want one taken away as long as it's colliding with the player its taking away lives, it will keep decrementing.

Hopefully this will give you some ideas :D